# What's the point of having foreign keys if Rails can access other model's attributes through associations anyways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails beginner (and loving it so far). I'm not sure if this is a stupid question.
As far as I know, a foreign key, for example, like this: `user_id` in a model called Micropost will associate a micropost with the ID of an User model. Like this:

[image]

[railtutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:microposts_resource)

So you can do this: `<%= micropost.user_id %>` to get the ID of the user who created a micropost.

But can also do this: `<%= micropost.user.id %>` due to Rails' ability to associate models via `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

- So I wonder, why are foreign keys necessary in Rails applications if the web framework can access other model's attributes through associations anyways?
- Is it necessary to index them and improve database performance?
- Or are they necessary so that something like this: `micropost.user.username` can work?

Answer (score 2):

Foreign keys are used under the hood to make Rails associations work, and those associations wouldn't work without them. You can see this  by attaching `.to_sql` to a Relation, e.g.:

```
> Blog.first.articles.to_sql
=> "SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles`  WHERE `articles`.`blog_id` = 42"
```

In this case it's using the `blog_id` foreign key to query the `articles` association.

It isn't necessary to index foreign keys, but it is a good idea and gives better performance.

Answer (score 2):

> So I wonder, why are foreign keys necessary in Rails applications if the web framework can access other model's attributes through associations anyways?

Foreign keys (along with the Primary key counter part) are what ***links*** the models together. If you did not have a `user_id` how would you know which `user` it ultimately is associated to?

> Is it necessary to index them and improve database performance?

I find this practice helpful, in regards to performance.

> Or are they necessary so that something like this: micropost.user.username can work?

It's only necessary in the context that to find `micropost`'s associated `user` you need to know which `user` it is.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to understand about `user` vs `user_id` in your model is that `user_id` is the foreign key and that `user` is an **instance** of a `User` (eg, it's the model object).

Without `user_id`, rails can't make the correct `user` for you.

Note that if you are not [preloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) your associations, if all you need is the user id (say, for a building a URL), using `micropost.user_id` will be faster than `micropost.user.id` because rails won't need to instantiate the `User` object just to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 0):

By calling micropost.user_id, Rails gives you the entry of the user_id column of the microposts table.
By calling micropost.user.id, Rails takes the user_id column from micropost and "searches" for Users with the corresponding id. When you do not have the user_id, Rails do not know anything about the correlation between the two tables.